# Shuffling items between two boxes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have two initially identical boxes. They each contain 1 red ball and 3 green balls.

From the first box, I randomly take out a ball and put it into the second box.

From that second box, I randomly take out a ball and put it into the first box.

Finally, I randomly take out a ball from the first box.

What's the probability that the said ball is red?

I would appreciate any tips on getting started.

Comment: I'm sure you've already drawn a picture. My guess is if you've learned conditional probability i.e. P(A|B) then it will probably use that somehow

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to note that in expectation, the two boxes are again identical after you've placed a ball from the second box back into the first, so the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$. Without any information, your best guess prior to drawing a ball a third time is that the boxes are the same as they were before you started the process. This is a consequence of the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Here's a **hint** on how to work through it the long way and prove it to yourself:

There are three ways you can pull the red ball:

1. The first ball was red and the second red.
2. The first ball was not red and the second ball was red.
3. The first ball was not red and the second ball was not red.

If the first ball was red and the second not red, there will be $0$ red balls in the first box, so it would be impossible to pull a red ball.

For the first option, there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of pulling the red ball first. After moving it, there are now $2$ red balls and $3$ green balls in the second box. So, there's a $\frac{2}{5}$ chance of pulling a red ball from the second box. There are now $1$ red and $3$ green balls in the first box, so we have a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of pulling the red ball from it. Overall, this sequence has probability $\frac{1}{4}*\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{40}$.

You should get that the second sequence of events has probability $\frac{3}{40}$, and the third has probability $\frac{3}{20}$, giving you a grand total of $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Would this reasoning change if we scaled up the number of each color balls but maintained their ratios? For example, if the two boxes began with 14 red balls and 42 green balls?

Comment: And how is it necessarily true that the boxes will be the same at the end of the process as you mentioned in the first paragraph? If I drew a red ball first, put the red ball into the second box, and drew a green ball and placed that into the red box, I would have the first box be 4 green and the second box be 2 red and 2 green...

Comment: The boxes don’t have to end up where they started, but since you don’t know what you drew each time, the expected value is the same as before moving them between boxes. That’s what the process going through the three sequences shows you. You can end up in different places, but when you take the expected value, it’s as if you never transferred the two balls.

Comment: If you started with 14 red balls and 42 green balls, the intermediate probabilities of the different sequences would change, but their sum would still come out to the same thing, $\frac{14}{56}=\frac{1}{4}$. Also, you’d have one more possibility, which would be red first, not red second - that has a nonzero probability of returning a red ball at the end if we have 14 in each box to begin with.